Is it bad practice to export all the names from one module both as named exports and as a default export?
I like to export the names in my modules both as individual named exports and grouped together in a default export. Like this:
// mod.js
export function f() {}
export const x = true

export default {f, x}

This gives me the ability to import both the whole module and individual named exports with a single line:
import Mod, {f} from './mod.js'

Without the default export I would need to use two import statements:
import * as Mod from './mod.js'
import {f} from './mod.js'


In order to export all the named exports in a single default export, I'm using the following trick to avoid having to repeat all the names (see Stack Overflow: How can I export all my named exports in a default object?):
// mod.js
export function f() {}
export const x = true

export * as default from './mod.js'

However, someone on that Stack Overflow question told me that this approach is bad practice, and I should import all symbols with import *, since it (the approach without default export):

works with any module regardless of its default export, and because it makes it immediately clear to the reader that myModule is a namespace object


Question:
Is it bad practice to export all the names from my module using my pattern?
I couldn't find any recommended approaches or other questions on this topic.

What makes the suggestion in the StackOverflow question a good practice?

Besides terseness, what advantage is there to importing the module and individual members from the same module you just imported?

I don't understand what you mean with "What makes the suggestion in the StackOverflow question a good practice?". Which suggestion?

And the only advantage of this approach is that I can do import Mod, {f}. Terseness is the only advantage, but for me it's important enough. I wonder whether I should do it the way I like it, or if it's considered bad practice and I should avoid doing that (at least for public modules, meant to be released online and used by others).

At first glance I had mixed feelings about this. On one hand, it is convenient because it saves you a few lines of code when using the module. In the other hand, it makes some assumptions about how your module will be used. Remember that this points to different objects based on how a JavaScript function is called. Calling f() and Mod.f() are not universally interchangeable for every module in cases where f() uses this inside the function definition.
If you are the module author, you know that f() does not access this. Consumers of your module, without referring to the source code, might not know that. Consumers of your module might write odd looking code, calling f() on one line, and then on another line calling Mod.f(). Odd, but not wrong for your module, and not necessarily correct for other modules.
There is no "best practice" here. The best guidance I can give is:

Follow what your other teammates are doing (if working in a team)
Follow the common idioms established by other modules or packages.
Don't confuse the consumers of your module.
Don't require consumers to know the implementation details of your module just to use it.

Many of these guidelines are open to interpretation, so there is no objective measure of "right" or "wrong" here.
